# Cannot upgrade Visual Studio Microsoft Teams project to new Teams Toolkit

Tags: visual-studio, teams-toolkit

I previously created a Microsoft Teams project with Visual Studio 2022 Release 17.3.  I have since upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 Release 17.8 and, with that, received the new version of Teams Toolkit.

I’m now unable to deploy the project because I’m missing the teamsapp.yml file.  (The new version of Teams Toolkit requires this file.)  According to the article below, I should be prompted to upgrade the project when I open it, but no such prompt is displayed.

[New Teams Toolkit for Visual Studio release with exciting features for .NET developers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/new-teams-toolkit-for-visual-studio-release-with-exciting-features-for-net-developers/)

Is there a way to manually force the project to upgrade to the new version of Teams Toolkit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As the Visual Studio 2022 Release 17.3 is not a long-term-support version.([Visual Studio support policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/release-rhythm)) The project created by it can not automatically upgrade.
You can upgrade it by two steps. Before you start the steps, you can use git to save the project, observe the project change in upgrade and rollback the upgrade if needed.

1. Set the Visual Studio to version 17.4 and open the project. The project will upgrade to the compatible version with version 17.8.
2. After upgrade in version 17.4, set the Visual Studio to version 17.8 and open the project again. This time the upgrade process will generate the teamsapp.yml file and upgrade to the newest version.

Comment: How do I "Set the Visual Studio to version 17.4"?  Is it a setting in Visual Studio?  If so, where do I change this setting?  Or do I need to install a new instance of Visual Studio 17.4?

Comment: Yes. A new instance of Visual Studio 17.4 is a good way. If there is difficulty to install Visual Studio 17.4, there could be another way to try. Not all projects were tested for this way. Before you try, use git or other vcs tool to save your project. 
1. You can use the VSCode and install the Teams Toolkit extension with version 4.2.x. Relaunch the VSCode, and open the project. It will upgrade the project to a compatible version with Visual Studio 17.8 as well.
2. Use Visual Studio 17.8 to open the project again.